# How to refresh expired token with API Client Library for Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

I use [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) to work with OAuth2. The credentials I get include `refresh_token` value. `credentials.access_token_expired` allows me to check if token is expired or not. But I don't understand from the documentation - if it is expired, am I supposed to refresh it manually (and how? call `credentials.refresh()`?) or is it done automatically and I don't need to refresh it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if what I do is correct or not.
It does not look to be good practice but it works.

I declare credentials that I receive from AppAssertionCredentials as a global variable.
I use it for an hour and it works fine. After this hour, the token is probably expired. If I test it using access_token_expired, I always receive false.
So, I make use of refresh method.

I also tried a brut force method and systematically invoke the refresh method and it works as well.

Code here

[Access Google spreadsheet from Google Appengine with service account : working once per hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081860/access-google-spreadsheet-from-google-appengine-with-service-account-working-o/36114406#36114406)